# Phonegap - resolução do app em diversos aparelhos

Tags: apache-cordova

Mais uma vez o Phonegap!

Fiz um app, usando html, css e jquery mobile que, se vc abrir ele como 'site' no Android, a tela fica de um tamanho (relativamente grande). Se você abre ele como app, em alguns aparelhos ele se adapta à tela, ficando com as letras muito pequenas, e em outros aparelhos, as letras ficam maiores, usando barra de rolagem. Vi essa diferença em versões do Android 4.2.2 e 5.0 (letras maiores) e 5.1 Lollipop (letras muito pequenas).

Existe alguma configuração para isso, no XML, por exemplo? Gostaria que, se possível, o app ficasse sempre com o tamanho que aparece como site (letras grandes).

Obrigado!!

Comment: Mas depende do site também, a configuração do [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) do site.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o seguinte na viewport: target-densitydpi=medium-dpi"

Comment: Pode explicar melhor como isso pode resolver o que foi perguntado?